# GDM does not start on void linux

Tags: login, gdm, void-linux

According to void wiki, I installed these packages: `xbps-install -S gnome-core gdm`. I also installed `dbus` package and enabled it on startup. The wiki then recommended to test the service, so i ran through the 3 commands, then after running `sudo sv once gdm`, a black screen with blinking cursor appears in top left corner.

Then I switched to tty1 and it was in cli (*user* login) mode, but after I start typing one letter, it immediately switches to the desktop and starts typing in the terminal (the gdm command got finished). The mouse pointer becomes invisible! This happens in typing the command in both xfce and gnome. I had to type `sudo reboot` to show the pointer again.

I saw in tty7 that the cursor was still blinking. How can I resolve this issue?

I used the xfce iso and it uses the default xfce display manager. How can I replace the default with gdm?

EDIT:Issue is solved! Disabling both lxdm and gdm, then enabling gdm did not autostart gdm, though lxdm autostarted immediately after enabling it. Then I saw a file named delete in /var/service/gdm which was not present in /var/service/lxdm. I opened it with gedit but it was empty. So I removed that file and disabled both the services, and enabled gdm, now it works! I wonder what the delete file was for?

Comment: Did you install xorg or wayland?